# SQL Server 2008 R2 Express edition limitation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have website running on SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard edition and on new server we are provided with SQL Server 2008 R2 Express edition. I am sure that there are certain limitations like

- maximum of 10GB of DB size per database
- Utilization of 1 process only
- Use of 1 GB Internal memory only.

I would like to is there any limitation on maximum number of concurrent connection in Express edition and how slow it can be when it comes to performance.

Comment: Your first question is answered by Microft here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/26b0ff66-4dca-4aaf-b36e-9708cf81b467/limitations-of-sql-server-2008-r2-express-users-connection-database?forum=sqlexpress and here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: For second question we need info on your current darabase setup and load.

Comment: There is no practical limitation as such. But since SQL Server express can use max of 1 CPU and just over 1 G of memory you wont be able to gain much mileage out of it.